# Coroutine Job operation at the push of a button

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

Declaration of variables

```
private lateinit var wayoJob: Job
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.Main + wayoJob
```

Function

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
private fun startRepeatingJob(timeInterval: Long): Job {
    return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        while (NonCancellable.isActive) {

            Log.i("API", "UPDATE")

            delay(timeInterval)
        }
    }
}
```

In the Start Button

```
wayoJob = startRepeatingJob(5000L)
```

In Button end and onDestroy()

```
wayoJob.cancel()
```

When I click the End button it returns an error:

**Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property wayoJob has not been initialized**

Is there any way around this?

I have to do a function that starts executing every few seconds when I press a button and will end when I click another button.

****EDIT:****

I could try something like this with my own `shouldBeActive` value and run when I need to, but that's not how it should be

```
var shouldBeActive = false

@InternalCoroutinesApi
private fun startRepeatingJob(timeInterval: Long): Job {
    return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        while (NonCancellable.isActive && shouldBeActive) {

            Log.i("API", "UPDATE")

            delay(timeInterval)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ that line in your start button is being run? That error should not happen if the variable is being initialized, which that would do.

Comment: @RyanM Yes, it is initialized. I added a Log and it shows up every 5 seconds. And when I click Stop, it throws an error that there is no initialization

Comment: @RyanM I found a solution. Check in the answers

Comment: Why do you show code that implements `CoroutineScope` for your class, but then you never use it and instead use an ad-hoc `CoroutineScope(Default)`? Also, the top-level job shouldn't be a `lateinit var` that keeps changing. You seem to be using syntactic elements of structured concurrency, but break the structured concurrency itself.

Comment: Your error message confirms what I said above, and your solution just adds more hacks around the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

I have an Activity reload and the object resets

The solution is to insert it like below. This solution ensures that no second object is created in the meantime

```
companion object {
    private lateinit var wayoJob: Job
}
```

**Sample whole class:**

```
class StartActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    companion object {
        private lateinit var wayoJob: Job
    }

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + wayoJob

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start)
    }

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    private fun startRepeatingJob(timeInterval: Long): Job {
        return CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
            while (NonCancellable.isActive) {

                Log.i("API", "UPDATE")

                delay(timeInterval)
            }
        }
    }

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    fun endBtnOnClick(view: View?) {
        wayoJob.cancel()
    }

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    fun startBtnOnClick(view: View?) {
        wayoJob = startRepeatingJob(5000L)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        wayoJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach will introduce bugs if multiple `StartActivity`s ever exist at the same time.  The `Job` should be per-instance, not global.